# NoMethodError - undefined method `get' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, redis, actioncable

Here is the tutorial which I follow for implement: [Finally Trying ActionCable](https://hired.com/blog/candidates/finally-trying-actioncable/)

This code is too long, so I don't put this code into this question I just put some of the codes as like into the user model

```
def online_now?
    $redis.get("users:online:#{id}").present?
end
```

and the view is:

```
<% User.all.each do |user| %>
    <%= user.name %>
    <div class="online-indicator">
        <% if !user.online_now? && 'xs-none' %>
            Online
        <% else %>
            Offline
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

but always throwing an error as like

> NoMethodError - undefined method `get' for nil:NilClass
>   Did you mean?  gem:
>     app/models/user.rb:34:in`online_now?'

which indicating this line

```
$redis.get("users:online:#{id}").present?
```

I don't why throwing this error.

But it's working on rails console as like

```
irb(main):005:0> redis.set("mykey", "hello world")
=> "OK"
irb(main):006:0> redis.get("mykey")
=> "hello world"
```

Thanks

Comment: `$redis` is nil. How you defined it?

Comment: `$redis.set "users:online:#{current_user.id}", 1` here is the line into subscribe method

Comment: No, @Pavan asked how do you define ```$redis``` variable in your model method. It's clear it should be a Redis API, but where do you connect to the Redis and store its connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From comment `@Ilya Konyukhov` how do you define `$redis` variable in your model method. It's clear it should be a Redis API, but where do you connect to the Redis and store its connection?

Yes, that is a very nice comment & helpful for clearing the concept from a commentator.

If your Redis server is running in the system then need to configure this in Rails own way, I would writing some configuration files & if you already created that you can compare these & if you not created till now I think that is the issue & need to create ASAP if you need this feature.

First, install the gem `redis-rails`

```
gem 'redis-rails'
```

after that add this into environment file

```
config.cache_store = :redis_store, {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 6379,
    db: 0,
    password: "mysecret",
    namespace: "cache"
}, {
    expires_in: 90.minutes
}
```

create a file into `app/config/initializer/` which `redis.rb` then put into this

```
$redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)
```

after all restart the server and check it out.

make sure `redis-server` is running.

Hope it will work.